# Meta-Nav and normal Nav TYPO3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

can me somebody explain me how this menu was made.

I need a menu like this and have no plan how.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1h1X.png

https://www.alesa.ch/en/

Thanks for the answers.

Edit:

So it's working now.

```html
<f:spaceless>
<div id="top"></div>
<div class="body-bg{f:if(condition:settings.navigation.type, then:' body-bg-{settings.navigation.type}')}">
    <a class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">
        <span>{f:translate(key: 'skiptomaincontent', extensionName: 'bootstrap_package')}</span>
    </a>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar-top navbar hidden-xs">
   <div class="container">
     <!-- right nav top -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
     <f:render partial="Navigation/Meta" arguments="{_all}" />
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <f:render partial="Navigation/Language2" arguments="{_all}" />
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <f:render partial="Navigation/Main" arguments="{_all}" />
 </nav>
    <f:render partial="Navigation/Breadcrumb" arguments="{_all}" />


    <div id="content" class="main-section">
        <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->
        <f:render section="Main" />
        <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->
    </div>

    <f:render partial="Structure/Footer" arguments="{_all}" />
    <f:render partial="Structure/ScrollTop" arguments="{_all}" />

</div>
</f:spaceless>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That metamenu are two menus.

left side: "...us de Schwiiz  Contact" are normal menu to pages
right side is a language menu (`special = language`)

Easy to define in typoscript. As you can see in the HTML of that page the menus are seperate HTML blocks (`<nav>`) and the language menu comes first (->floating)

Comment: Your post help me only to 50%, i am still a typo3 noob :D

Comment: Your edit shows the correct way (one way, as there are always multiple). now you need to define your two partials. Either you define the menus in typoscript (so it would be just two variabel insertions (`{metaMenu->f:format.raw()}` and `{languageMenu->f:format.raw()}`) or you build up the complete menus in fluid, which can be done since TYPO3 8. As I'm more familiar with the older versions, my solution would be typoscript, which you can find multiple times in the net. search for: language menu, meta menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this Typoscript-Snippet:

```
lib.metanav = HMENU
lib.metanav {
    special = directory
    special.value = <uid-of-sysfolder-or-page-holding-the-items>

    wrap = <ul class="metanav">|</ul>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>| &#124; </li> |*| <li> | &#124; </li> |*| <li>|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

Pipes as menu item separator have to be decoded this way `&#124;` because the pipe character itself in typoscript is reserverd for wraps.

Comment: "Try this..." is not a question, it's a statement. Please elaborate on what you need so we can help you.

Comment: you have missed that there are two parts in the example menu. there are two pages linked, but there also is a language switching menu for three languages. the pipes only occur in the language menu.